# Working with HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to get a link and another element from an HTML page, but I don't really know what to do. This is what I have right now:

```
var client = new HtmlWeb(); // Initialize HtmlAgilityPack's functions.
var url = "http://p.thedgtl.net/index.php?tag=-1&title={0}&author=&o=u&od=d&page=-1&"; // The site/page we are indexing.
var doc = client.Load(string.Format(url, textBox1.Text)); // Index the whole DB.
var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]"); // Get every url.

string authorName = "";
string fileName = "";
string fileNameWithExt;

foreach (HtmlNode link in nodes)
{
    string completeUrl = link.Attributes["href"].Value; // The complete plugin download url.

    #region Get all jars

    if (completeUrl.Contains(".jar")) // Check if the url contains .jar
    {
        fileNameWithExt = completeUrl.Substring(completeUrl.LastIndexOf('/') + 1); // Get the filename with extension.
        fileName = fileNameWithExt.Remove(fileNameWithExt.LastIndexOf('.')); ; // Get the filename without extension.
        Console.WriteLine(fileName);
    }

    #endregion

    #region Get all Authors

    if (completeUrl.Contains("?author=")) // Check if the url contains .jar
    {
        authorName = completeUrl.Substring(completeUrl.LastIndexOf('=') + 1); // Get the filename with extension.
        Console.WriteLine(authorName);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

I am trying to get all the filenames and authors next to each other, but now everything is like randomly placed, why?

Can someone help me with this? Thanks!

Comment: What if a URL contains only one of `.jar` and `?author=`?

Comment: That's good, because with that check I can detect if it's a author or a normal link :).

Comment: My question was posted in order for you to think about what will happen in such an eventuality - what would your code do?

Comment: @Oded I thought that it will scan for every link and author and put them next to each other, but it doesn't seem to work like that.

Comment: Like I said - what would happen if a URL contains only one of `.jar` and `?author=`? Go through your code line by line for the 4 permutations (only one or the other, both exist or neither).

Comment: @Oded Wait, is it possible to search every <tr> (table row) and store that information in separate string or something?

Comment: Um. Sure. You can select all `<tr>` nodes.

Comment: @Oded How am I about to do something like that :o? And is it like a goo dsolution?

Comment: The same way you were getting all URLs: `doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("tr")`. I don't know if it will work for you. Try it. If it works, it is a good solution ;)

Comment: @Oded Thanks, always so close to the solution, I will try this :), can I still ask for advice if it doesn't work tho?

Comment: Doesn't work is not very descriptive...

Comment: @Oded VS says: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Comment: On what line? What you try to do _what_?

Comment: Unfortunately the html you get back isn't very well-formed.  So getting the right queries will be tough.

Comment: I've did this `var trs = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("tr");` instead of `var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]");` then I used a foreach and did this `foreach (HtmlNode link in trs)` which gives me the error :(.

Comment: @JeffMercado - The HAP deals well with malformed HTML.

Comment: @Oded: Sure it can parse it fine, but the structure won't be as expected. HAP doesn't handle open tags very well in my experience so you often have to workaround that limitation which is a PITA.

Comment: @Oded That worked like a charm :)! Now I need to find out how to search through those trs, any suggestions :o?

Comment: @Oded :o, damn I think I'm thinking to hard...

Comment: @Oded I only receive `HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNodeCollection` when I do the `SelectNodes` again. (I also can't seem to find any examples of this).

Comment: Download the source package - there are lots of sample projects that come with it. It will give you a good idea of how to work with it.

Comment: Don't feel bad, this is some nasty stuff, I'm working on an answer for you.

Comment: @JeffMercado Alright, thanks Jeff, I'm searching the samples that Oded suggested to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the HTML, it's very unfortunate it is not well-formed.  There's a lot of open tags and the way HAP structures it is not like a browser, it interprets the majority of the document as deeply nested.  So you can't just simply iterate through the rows of the table like you would in the browser, it gets a lot more complicated than that.

When dealing with such documents, you have to change your queries quite a bit.  Rather than searching through child elements, you have to search through descendants adjusting for the change.

```
var title = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(textBox1.Text);
var url = String.Format("http://p.thedgtl.net/index.php?title={0}", title);

var web = new HtmlWeb();
var doc = web.Load(url);

// select the rows in the table
var xpath = "//div[@class='content']/div[@class='pluginList']/table[2]";
var table = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(xpath);

// unfortunately the `tr` tags are not closed so HAP interprets
// this table having a single row with multiple descendant `tr`s
var rows = table.Descendants("tr")
    .Skip(1); // skip header row

var query =
    from row in rows
    // there may be a row with an embedded ad
    where row.SelectSingleNode("td/script") == null
    // each row has 6 columns so we need to grab the next 6 descendants
    let columns = row.Descendants("td").Take(6).ToList()
    let titleText = columns[1].Elements("a").Select(a => a.InnerText).FirstOrDefault()
    let authorText = columns[2].Elements("a").Select(a => a.InnerText).FirstOrDefault()
    let downloadLink = columns[5].Elements("a").Select(a => a.GetAttributeValue("href", null)).FirstOrDefault()
    select new
    {
        Title = titleText ?? "",
        Author = authorText ?? "",
        FileName = Path.GetFileName(downloadLink ?? ""),
    };
```

So now you can just iterate through the query and write out what you want for each of the rows.

```
foreach (var item in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", item.FileName, item.Author);
}
```

Comment: Wow, a thousand thanks :o! I didn't heard of xpath yet, going to look into that and this code works like a charm :o!